# how to assign data from search option to json format in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

```
My Mysql table is in following format and with json format for shows_id 

id |  assign_id  |  rights    | party      |shows_id
---+-------------+------------+------------+---------
1  |4            |  12        | xyz        | ["2","3","13","14"]
2  |4            |   5        | xyz        | ["2","3","13","59"]
3  |6            |  14        | abc        | ["56","57","59","60"]
4  |6            |  5         | abc        | ["56","57","59","60"]
5  |7            |  12        | def        | ["2","41","42","54"]
6  |7            |  5         | def        | ["2","41","42","59"]
```

I want  my output  in table format :
         Search Result For rights 5

```
     | party                |shows_id
-----+----------------------+----------
     | xyz  ,def            | 2
     | xyz                  | 3
     | xyz                  |13
     | xyz ,def,abc         |59
     | abc                  | 56         
     | abc                  | 57
     | abc                  | 59
     | abc                  | 60
     | def                  | 41
     | def                  | 42
```

I get all id of `shows_id` in array, but how can I display party name against it if Kcomes in three party?

Comment: not getting what you want

Comment: In my search result : If  rights column,  contains 5 all shows_id with right 5 will be displayed against their party name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the provided design, it is not possible to get the output described above, as shows_id is stored as a (json) string (it's not good design as well). I would suggest creating a new table with `party` and `show_id` columns to store these mappings and then, we can query that table to generate the desired output.

Let's say we have `shows` table that stores these mappings, [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3eb3f/1/0) SQL Fiddle describes how to generate the output.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. This table design is **very bad** for retrieval of such data. I suggest changing it to something like that:

```
party:
  ID
  assign_id
  rights
  party

party_shows:
  party_id
  shows_id
```

Then it'll be quite easy to retrieve data, using following query:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT party.party ORDER BY party.party SEPARATOR ','), party_shows.shows_id
FROM party
INNER JOIN party_shows ON party.id=party_shows.party_id
GROUP BY party_shows.shows_id`

You'll also be able to query for a specific shows_id.

**In your design, you won't be able to use 'pure' MySQL query. You also have to ask for a WHOLE table to display anything. This will be suicidal for bigger database.**

But - there is a possibility to prepare results according to your wish. It'll look similar to the following pseudocode:

```
$pdo = getDbConnection(); //Let's assume you retrieve your DB connection here, as PDO
$sql = "SELECT * FROM party";
$results = $pdo->query($sql);
$return = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $shows = json_decode($result['shows_id'], true);
    foreach ($shows as $show_id) {
        if (empty($return[$show_id])) {
            $return[$show_id] = array($result['party']);
        } else {
            $return[$show_id][] = $result['party'];
        }
    }
}
foreach ($return as &$return_row) {
    $return_row = implode(',', array_unique($return_row));
}
```

Now, you have `$return` table, where each row is string with party names. Keys for `$return` array are show IDs, so you can further filter by it.

I have to say once again: **this is NOT a good way**. But it is possible.

As a final note: your table structure (repeating party names in table) indicates, that the whole structure needs further decoupling. As a general rule - each entity (party, user, party shows) should appear as ONE row. So you should have table for parties, assignees, shows etc with appropriate join tables. Maybe something like that:

```
assignee:
    id
    name
assignee_party:
    assignee_id
    party_id
    rights
party:
    id
    party
party_shows:
    party_id
    show_id
```

But that's just a pure guess, I won't be able to tell more without knowledge of the whole structure and purpose of the table.